# reloading of react component in a tab

Tags: reactjs, dom, tabs, jsx

I created a react component  that is basically a table. I called  using a function with some parameters f(X, idPlaceholder). So f behaves like:

```
f(X, idPlaceholder) {
   ....
   ReactDom.render(
   <T  ... />
  ,
  document.getElementById(idPlaceholder)
  )
}

' <T/> ' shows different stuff according to the values of X. However, when used on a tab control using something like:

    if  (selectionIndex == 1) {
          idPlaceholder = 'pos1'
          f(a, idPlaceholder)
     }
     if  (selectionIndex == 2) {
          idPlaceholder = 'pos2'
          f(b, idPlaceholder)
     }
     if  (selectionIndex == 3) {
          idPlaceholder = 'pos3'
          f(c, idPlaceholder)
     }
```

If I select a tab from these choices the content shows most of the previous selected tab and nearly nothing of what should appear on the selected one.

Any ideas of why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: This smells like a `key` issue; are you doing any iteration to create elements (e.g., a map function over some data to dynamically create rows, etc.)  If so, you need to ensure each dynamically created component is passed a unique `key` prop

Comment: Yes, I am doing that...

Comment: Hmm - okay. Can you post the "table" component's code?

Comment: I added a key props just as you said doing something like:  <T key = {X} />  and all started to work! Thanks